# SOGo: CalDAV Entries not showing in Client (iOS, macOS, Android)

Tags: caldav

we have set up a CalDAV server here with SOGo as backend and frontend (WEBUI). Which is working as expected.

But there are some errors which I cannot reproduce and the logging also gives no hint since there is no logging:
1) macOS 10.11 - latest release
I can login to CalDAV, I can create entries (which are synced) and they show up in WEBUI. But events created in WEBUI are not synced.

2) Same credentials, same usage on iPhone iOS12 - I can't even log in to the calender.

Here the HTTP error in the log indicates a "Forbidden"...but as stated the credentials are correct - maybe iOS sends a authentication methode which is not installed on my server?

Dan

Comment: This is not a programming question, maybe head over to Superuser. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is very simple and seems intuitive:

1. Install SSL certificate for https connections to SOGo web-root
2. Forward all http requests to https